# SQL Bowling Score Calculations

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm still a SQL noob and I've been struggling with this problem for quite some time and am finally at my wits end, and thus I must ask for assistance.
I am attempting to calculate the score of a bowlers game but don't understand how to do math on columns within the same table as well as put in the logic to handle when it's an open frame, strike or spare, and the 10th frame. The table that holds the game data is this:

```
TYearLeagueGamePlayerFrameThrows
     intYearID
    ,intLeagueID
    ,intTeamID
    ,intGameID
    ,intGameSetIndex
    ,intPlayerID
    ,intFrameID
    ,intTurnID
    ,intThrowPinCount
```

So for one bowlers game the inserts look like:

```
             ( 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 9 )  
        ,( 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1 ) 
        ,( 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 8 )
        ,( 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 0 )
        ,( 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 10 )
        ,( 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 1, 10 )
        ,( 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 5, 1, 7 )
        ,( 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 5, 2, 2 )
        ,( 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 6, 1, 9 )
        ,( 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 6, 2, 0 )
        ,( 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 7, 1, 6 )
        ,( 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 7, 2, 3 )
        ,( 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 8, 1, 1 )
        ,( 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 8, 2, 9 )
        ,( 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 9, 1, 7 )
        ,( 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 9, 2, 2 ) 
        ,( 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 10, 1, 9 )
        ,( 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 10, 2, 1 )
        ,( 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 10, 3, 8 )
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!!

The only thing I've been able to come up with so far is this, but the totals are wrong:

```
  DECLARE    @TurnID    AS INTEGER
        ,@Count     AS INTEGER
        ,@Frame     AS INTEGER
        ,@Score     AS INTEGER
        ,@Value     AS INTEGER
        ,@Throw1    AS INTEGER
        ,@Throw2    AS INTEGER
        ,@Throw3    AS INTEGER
        ,@Throw4    AS INTEGER
        ,@Total     AS INTEGER

SELECT 
    TOP 21 
    intTurnID 
    ,intPlayerID 

FROM 
     TYearLeagueTeamPlayerGameFrameThrows 

WHERE
    intPlayerID = @intPlayerID 
ORDER BY

      intTurnID 
     ,intFrameID 

SET @Count      = @@ROWCOUNT 
SET @TurnID     = 1
SET @Frame      = 0
SET @Score      = 0
SET @Total      = 0

WHILE @Frame < 10 AND @TurnID < @Count 
    BEGIN

    SET @Frame  = @Frame + 1


SELECT 
    @Throw1 = intThrowPinCount 
FROM 
    TYearLeagueTeamPlayerGameFrameThrows 
WHERE
    intFrameID  = 1
AND 
    intThrowPinCount = @TurnID 

SELECT
    @Throw2 = intThrowPinCount 
FROM
    TYearLeagueTeamPlayerGameFrameThrows 
WHERE
    intFrameID  = 1
AND 
    intThrowPinCount = @TurnID + 1

SELECT 
    @Throw3 = intThrowPinCount
FROM
    TYearLeagueTeamPlayerGameFrameThrows 
WHERE
    intFrameID = 2
AND 
    intThrowPinCount = @TurnID + 2


SET @Value = 
    CASE
    WHEN @Throw1            = 10 THEN @Throw1 + @Throw2 + @Throw3 --STRIKE
    WHEN @Throw1 + @Throw2  = 10 THEN @Throw1 + @Throw2 + @Throw3 --SPARE
    ELSE @Throw1 + @Throw2 

END

SET @TurnID = @TurnID + 
    CASE 
    WHEN @Throw1            = 10 THEN 3 --STRIKE
    WHEN @Throw1 + @Throw2  = 10 THEN 2 --SPARE
    ELSE 1

END

SET @Score = @Score + @Value 
    IF @Throw1 + @Throw2 <= 10 or @Throw3 IS NOT NULL
        PRINT 'FRAME: ' + str(@Frame, 2 ) + '  Score: ' + str(@Score, 3 )  
END
```

The frames and game should total to be:

```
Frame 1 = 18
Frame 2 = 26
Frame 3 = 53
Frame 4 = 72
Frame 5 = 81
Frame 6 = 90
Frame 7 = 99
Frame 8 = 116
Frame 9 = 125
Frame 10 = 143 - Final Score
```

Comment: SQL sounds like the wrong tool for this. It *can* do it, but it *shouldn't*.

Comment: You forgot to post any SQL at all, or to even ask a question. What specifically would you like help with? And what have you attempted yourself to try and find a solution? (Bowling score calculations are rather complicated, and doing so in SQL is going to get gnarly pretty quickly. @DanielMann has a very good point.)

Comment: @DanielMann, Indeed this would be much easier to in another language, but I'm focusing on learning sql.

Comment: All you're learning with this exercise is how to use SQL to perform tasks that it's ill-suited to perform.

Comment: @KenWhite, I guess I should have phrased better, I need help understanding how to write the query that would calculate the score for a game.  I don't understand how to do calculate columns from within the same table, ie frame 1 throw 1 and 2, and also what the logic would be for when it's an open frame, strike, spare.

Comment: @kenWhite, I really think it's obvious what the question is from my original post, where I say I what I want to achieve and what I don't understand.

Comment: Can you provide the results that you are expecting for the data you provide?

Comment: @GordonLinoff, just edited to show what the scores should be.

Comment: @DanielMann, I did not find ANY difficulties in computing the scores across the board... Sometimes it means you have to step back and simplify a problem in parts (pivot) before trying to compute score (via very simple case/when) conditions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following may look complex, but it runs accurately in SQL-Server (or most other SQL too).  First, the inner-most query.  Here, I am creating a cross-tab on a per year, league, team, game, set and player grouping.

I am explicitly doing a case/when for each possible frame and shot to create a single row per person such that it would resemble that of a bowling game where the column names are "F"rame + "S"hot such that F1S1 = Frame1, Shot1,  F1S2 = Frame1, Shot2, and in the 10th frame, F10S1, F10S2 F10S3.  So now that we have every person rolled-up to a single row PER GAME, PER Set, etc, we can now compute the score on a frame-by-frame basis.

So, for each frame, I am doing a case/when and have it explicitly copied for all 10 frames as each frame can rely on UP TO the following 2 frames and I think you'll directly follow the logic.

I am testing for a double current and next frame are strikes as that is the most any set of frames is compared against. So.

```
If    Frame1 Shot1 is 10 (strike) 
  AND Frame2 Shot1 is 10 (strike), then 20 + whatever was Frame3 Shot1

If    Frame1 Shot1 is 10 (strike)
  AND Frame2 Shot1 is LESS than 10, then 10 + BOTH shots in Frame2

If neither condition in Frame 1 was a strike, test for a spare
if   Frame1 Shot1 + Frame1 Shot2 is 10 (spare), then 10 + first shot in Frame2

if neither a strike or a spare, just add Frame1 Shot1 + Frame1 Shot2.

Take that result and apply the same, but shift for the represenative frames.
If Frame2 Shot1 is 10 and Frame3 Shot1 is 10, then 20 + Frame4 Shot1
etc...

select
      Game.intYearID,
      Game.intLeagueID,
      Game.intTeamID,
      Game.intGameID,
      Game.intGameSetIndex,
      Game.intPlayerID,
      case when Game.F1S1 = 10 and Game.F2S1 = 10 then 20 + Game.F3S1
           when Game.F1S1 = 10 and Game.F2S1 < 10 then 10 + Game.F2S1 + Game.F2S2
           when Game.F1S1 + Game.F1S2 = 10 then 10 + Game.F2S1
           else Game.F1S1 + Game.F1S2 end
    +  case when Game.F2S1 = 10 and Game.F3S1 = 10 then 20 + Game.F4S1
           when Game.F2S1 = 10 and Game.F3S1 < 10 then 10 + Game.F3S1 + Game.F3S2
           when Game.F2S1 + Game.F2S2 = 10 then 10 + Game.F3S1
           else Game.F2S1 + Game.F2S2 end
    +  case when Game.F3S1 = 10 and Game.F4S1 = 10 then 20 + Game.F5S1
           when Game.F3S1 = 10 and Game.F4S1 < 10 then 10 + Game.F4S1 + Game.F4S2
           when Game.F3S1 + Game.F3S2 = 10 then 10 + Game.F4S1
           else Game.F3S1 + Game.F3S2 end
    +  case when Game.F4S1 = 10 and Game.F5S1 = 10 then 20 + Game.F6S1
           when Game.F4S1 = 10 and Game.F5S1 < 10 then 10 + Game.F5S1 + Game.F5S2
           when Game.F4S1 + Game.F4S2 = 10 then 10 + Game.F5S1
           else Game.F4S1 + Game.F4S2 end
    +  case when Game.F5S1 = 10 and Game.F6S1 = 10 then 20 + Game.F7S1
           when Game.F5S1 = 10 and Game.F6S1 < 10 then 10 + Game.F6S1 + Game.F6S2
           when Game.F5S1 + Game.F5S2 = 10 then 10 + Game.F6S1
           else Game.F5S1 + Game.F5S2 end
    +  case when Game.F6S1 = 10 and Game.F7S1 = 10 then 20 + Game.F8S1
           when Game.F6S1 = 10 and Game.F7S1 < 10 then 10 + Game.F7S1 + Game.F7S2
           when Game.F6S1 + Game.F6S2 = 10 then 10 + Game.F7S1
           else Game.F6S1 + Game.F6S2 end
    +  case when Game.F7S1 = 10 and Game.F8S1 = 10 then 20 + Game.F9S1
           when Game.F7S1 = 10 and Game.F8S1 < 10 then 10 + Game.F8S1 + Game.F8S2
           when Game.F7S1 + Game.F7S2 = 10 then 10 + Game.F8S1
           else Game.F7S1 + Game.F7S2 end
    +  case when Game.F8S1 = 10 and Game.F9S1 = 10 then 20 + Game.F10S1
           when Game.F8S1 = 10 and Game.F9S1 < 10 then 10 + Game.F9S1 + Game.F9S2
           when Game.F8S1 + Game.F8S2 = 10 then 10 + Game.F9S1
           else Game.F8S1 + Game.F8S2 end
    +  case when Game.F9S1 = 10 and Game.F10S1 = 10 then 20 + Game.F10S2
           when Game.F9S1 = 10 and Game.F10S1 < 10 then 10 + Game.F10S1 + Game.F10S2
           when Game.F9S1 + Game.F9S2 = 10 then 10 + Game.F10S1
           else Game.F9S1 + Game.F9S2 end
    +  case when Game.F10S1 = 10 and Game.F10S2 = 10 then 20 + Game.F10S3
           when Game.F10S1 = 10 and Game.F10S2 < 10 then 10 + Game.F10S2 + Game.F10S3
           when Game.F10S1 + Game.F10S2 = 10 then 10 + Game.F10S3
           else Game.F10S1 + Game.F10S2 end
      as GameScore
   from 
      ( select
              TY.intYearID,
              TY.intLeagueID,
              TY.intTeamID,
              TY.intGameID,
              TY.intGameSetIndex,
              TY.intPlayerID,
              sum( case when TY.intFrameID = 1 and TY.intTurnID = 1 then TY.intThrowPinCount else 0 end ) F1S1,
              sum( case when TY.intFrameID = 1 and TY.intTurnID = 2 then TY.intThrowPinCount else 0 end ) F1S2,
              sum( case when TY.intFrameID = 2 and TY.intTurnID = 1 then TY.intThrowPinCount else 0 end ) F2S1,
              sum( case when TY.intFrameID = 2 and TY.intTurnID = 2 then TY.intThrowPinCount else 0 end ) F2S2,
              sum( case when TY.intFrameID = 3 and TY.intTurnID = 1 then TY.intThrowPinCount else 0 end ) F3S1,
              sum( case when TY.intFrameID = 3 and TY.intTurnID = 2 then TY.intThrowPinCount else 0 end ) F3S2,
              sum( case when TY.intFrameID = 4 and TY.intTurnID = 1 then TY.intThrowPinCount else 0 end ) F4S1,
              sum( case when TY.intFrameID = 4 and TY.intTurnID = 2 then TY.intThrowPinCount else 0 end ) F4S2,
              sum( case when TY.intFrameID = 5 and TY.intTurnID = 1 then TY.intThrowPinCount else 0 end ) F5S1,
              sum( case when TY.intFrameID = 5 and TY.intTurnID = 2 then TY.intThrowPinCount else 0 end ) F5S2,
              sum( case when TY.intFrameID = 6 and TY.intTurnID = 1 then TY.intThrowPinCount else 0 end ) F6S1,
              sum( case when TY.intFrameID = 6 and TY.intTurnID = 2 then TY.intThrowPinCount else 0 end ) F6S2,
              sum( case when TY.intFrameID = 7 and TY.intTurnID = 1 then TY.intThrowPinCount else 0 end ) F7S1,
              sum( case when TY.intFrameID = 7 and TY.intTurnID = 2 then TY.intThrowPinCount else 0 end ) F7S2,
              sum( case when TY.intFrameID = 8 and TY.intTurnID = 1 then TY.intThrowPinCount else 0 end ) F8S1,
              sum( case when TY.intFrameID = 8 and TY.intTurnID = 2 then TY.intThrowPinCount else 0 end ) F8S2,
              sum( case when TY.intFrameID = 9 and TY.intTurnID = 1 then TY.intThrowPinCount else 0 end ) F9S1,
              sum( case when TY.intFrameID = 9 and TY.intTurnID = 2 then TY.intThrowPinCount else 0 end ) F9S2,
              sum( case when TY.intFrameID = 10 and TY.intTurnID = 1 then TY.intThrowPinCount else 0 end ) F10S1,
              sum( case when TY.intFrameID = 10 and TY.intTurnID = 2 then TY.intThrowPinCount else 0 end ) F10S2,
              sum( case when TY.intFrameID = 10 and TY.intTurnID = 3 then TY.intThrowPinCount else 0 end ) F10S3
           from
              TYearLeagueGamePlayerFrameThrows TY
           group by
              TY.intYearID,
              TY.intLeagueID,
              TY.intTeamID,
              TY.intGameID,
              TY.intGameSetIndex,
              TY.intPlayerID ) Game
```

So, NOW, if you want the top 21 scores from the data, just do an

```
order by
   GameScore DESC
```

Comment: This is beautiful!  Thank you so much!  I've spent so much time trying to make this complicated because I thought it had to be complicated, but it totally makes so much more sense to just go frame by frame, shot by shot. If my reputation was higher I would upvote the heck out of this post! Thank you again.

Comment: @ryroanderson, you can always come back to upvote in the future... Now, for any WHERE conditions... If you only wanted a specific league or year, just put that in the inner-most query that is doing the PIVOT portion to get just the year/league, whatever.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know bowling but this may be a start (forgive my renaming of columns):

```
select FrameId, sum(ThrowPinCount)
, scorecard = (case when isStrike = 1 then 'X'  
               when sum(ThrowPinCount) = 10 then '/' 
               else cast(sum(ThrowPinCount) as nvarchar(5)) end)
from (
    select FrameId, TurnID, ThrowPinCount
    , isStrike = (case when ThrowPinCount = 10 then 1 else 0 end)
    from #YearLeagueGamePlayerFrameThrows
) results
group by FrameID, isstrike
order by frameid
```